# Byte to ASCII conversion Generating Unneeded/Undesired Spacing Characters

Tags: c#, type-conversion, ascii, whitespace

I have a code that relies heavily on bytes for its speed while not writing to a file.

In either the read function or the datapoint conversion function, I am getting several unnecessary "space" characters from the byte array after converting it to an ASCII string, even after setting them to ***NULL***. This generates a lot of undesired whitespace. Here's parts of the current code:

```
//Within Read Function
var charBuf = Enumerable.Repeat<byte>(0, 1024).ToArray(); //Set byte array to null
int ret = Read(ConnectionID, charBuf, 1024); //Call to a custom dll to retrieve data
if (0 <= ret)
{
    return charBuf;
}

//Datapoint message is set as an empty byte that gets added to the list Datapoint
//The following converts the datapoint to a string depending on its input
var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataPoint.Message);
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
{
    message = "ReadError";
}
```

Is there any way to eliminate these supposed characters without too much code or is there an error in my conversion? Either fix would be appreciated.

Comment: What data format does the `Read()` call in the dll need? `char *` or `wchar_t *` or something else? Can you hexdump the contents of the `charBuf` after a read? I don't think the `Encoding.ASCII` conversion is faulty, **if** the data format of that `Message` really is ASCII.

Comment: The dll is not mine, so I do not know. The dll is from a source that no longer exists and was not documented very well. However, the default C# code recommended had charBuf as a char array. I just changed it to byte for speed reasons. The error occured whether it was a char array or a byte.

Comment: Note that I've also used the following with no luck:
                message.Replace("\0", string.Empty);
                message.Replace("  ", string.Empty);
                message.TrimEnd(' ');
                message.TrimEnd('\0');

Comment: Maybe they aren't even nullbytes. Can you provide a hexdump of the `byte[] dataPoint.Message` and the resulting `string message`? (output of `BitConverter.ToString(dataPoint.Message)` prefferably).

Comment: Perhaps it should be `Encoding.Default` (i.e. it's ANSI text). Almost no Windows programs really use ASCII text.

Comment: Crystal ball says that you are using the wrong GetString() overload.  Surely you'll like GetString(charbuf, 0, ret) better.

Comment: Also, a more usual way to declare an array of 1024 bytes is `var charBuf = new byte[1024];`

Comment: The usual way of declaring an array returns the same issue. I will try default encoding, though I doubt it will do anything.

Comment: Hexdump: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwr1M0WsOOs1VVoxU25kUkNHbUE.                                           The -00- seems to be getting turned into a space character instead of being treated as a null. I've also already tried using 'Encoding.Default' with no luck. Do I simply need to use a for loop to eliminate the unnecessary characters? I'd hate to do that, but it seems to be the only solution at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent modifying the read function of the code too much further than changing the datatype in order to optimize the speed of the code, I decided to take care of the empty space issue by having the process of string simplification done once the read function was no longer in use, and all the data was being written to a file:

```
            var message = Encoding.Default.GetString(dataPoint.Message);
            int messageSize=0;
            byte nullByte = 0x00;
            for (int k=0; k < dataPoint.Message.Count(); k++)
            {
                if (dataPoint.Message.ElementAt(k).Equals(nullByte))
                {
                    messageSize = k+1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            message = message.Substring(0, messageSize);
```

message would then be appended to a text file line by line for each message per line.

This method ensures that despite being defined as 1024 null spaces, only data received by the read function will be accounted for (where the data being received sends no spaces).